# How to establish a connection between device shadow and dynamo db using aws iotcore

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-iot, dynamodb-queries

I have created a thing, and it contains its respective device shadow information. 
How can one post, update, delete information of device shadow into dynamo db?
How can i do it using IOT core.
I am stuck with device shadow and dynamo DB. 
the information provided by aws could not guide me the procedure to do it.
Please help me,
Thanks in Advance
Supriya

I have created a thing and its respective certificates. But when i created new rules under act. I am unable to connect it the existing thing.

Expected results are that device shadow information will be visible in dynamo db in a table created , that table can be accessed using primary key.

Unable to establish the connection at all.

Answer (score 0):

Create an iot rule that listens to your shadow topic and invokes a lambda function to write your data to DynamoDB.